# Should I use a private function as the best way to return a value from a case statement?

Tags: c#

In my program I have coded the following private variables and function.

```
    private string _viewName;
    private string _refValue;

    private void getContentDetails(string id) {
        switch (id.Substring(2, 2))
        {
            case "00": _refValue = "14"; _viewName = "Menu"; break;
            case "01": _refValue = "18"; _viewName = "Topic";  break;
            default: _refValue = "00"; _viewName = "Menu"; break;
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a better way to code this and I was thinking of replacing this with two private functions.

```
   getViewName(id);
   getRefValue(id);
```

Can someone suggest what might be the best way that I could code this?

Comment: That code will not compile, can you post your actual code.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Add a return type "void" to the method and it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly not wrong to put more than one statement in a switch, but it looks like there could be some duplication here, especially if the needed values that are coupled with an ID are changed.

It seems to me that you would have to use a map collection object for both `viewName` and `refValue` that maps the id's with the corresponding values. Then use `yourCollection.get(id);`. That will certainly keep your code best maintainable and consistent.

```
Dictionary<string, string> _refValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> _viewNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
fillDictionaries();

void fillDictionaries()
{
    _refValues.add("00","14"); //one way to add a value
    _viewNames["00"] = "Menu"; //another way to add a value
}

string getRefValue(string id)
{
    return _refvalues[id]; //there may be a get method but I'm not using an IDE atm
}

//same function for viewNames
```

This is not even yet the best solution. The best would be that you use a dictionary to couple the refValues to the viewNames, and then another dictionary that maps the ids to the refvalues. You can then get the refValue by using the id as key, and then the returned refValue as the key to get the viewName. Hope I made myself clear :)

Comment: I think the map idea sounds very good but I am not at all sure how to implement this. Can you suggest just for the one variable how I could do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a class:

```
class ContentDetails
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public string RefValue { get; set; }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
switch (id.Substring(2, 2))
{
    case "00": return new ContentDetails { RefValue = "14", ViewName = "Menu" };
    case "01": return new ContentDetails { RefValue = "18", ViewName = "Topic" };
    default: return new ContentDetails { RefValue = "00", ViewName = "Menu" };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to return multiple values.

You can use `out` parameters:

```
private void getContentDetails(string id, out string viewName, out string refValue) {
  switch (id.Substring(2, 2)) {
    case "00": refValue = "14"; viewName = "Menu"; break;
    case "01": refValue = "18"; viewName = "Topic";  break;
    default: refValue = "00"; viewName = "Menu"; break;
  }
}
```

You can return an object that contains two values:

```
private KeyValuePair<string, string> getContentDetails(string id) {
  switch (id.Substring(2, 2)) {
    case "00": return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Menu", "14");
    case "01": return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Topic", "18");
    default: return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Menu", "00");
  }
}
```

You can create your own object to return:

```
private class ContentDetails {

  public string ViewName { get; private set; }
  public string RefValue { get; private set; }

  public ContentDetails(string name, value) {
    ViewName = name;
    RefValue = value;
  }

}

private ContentDetails getContentDetails(string id) {
  switch (id.Substring(2, 2)) {
    case "00": return new ContentDetails("Menu", "14");
    case "01": return new ContentDetails("Topic", "18");
    default: return new ContentDetails("Menu", "00");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see an issue with using private globals in a class, if you wanted an alternate you could pass them by reference and as an out parameter.

```
private getContentDetails(string id, ref string refValue, ref string viewName)

private getContentDetails(string id, out string refValue, out string viewName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this class which implements maps (as Mario suggests).

The `idValueDictionary` maps the `id` to the `refValue`, and the `valueNameDictionary` maps the `refValue` to the `nameValue`. The dictionaries are hard-coded, though you could load the data at runtime if it suits your need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ContentDetails
{
  // Maps id to RefValue.
  private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> idValueDictionary =
    new Dictionary<string,string>()
    {
      { "00", "14" },
      { "01", "18" },
      { "XX", "00" }
    };

  // Maps RefValue to ViewName
  private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> valueNameDictionary =
    new Dictionary<string,string>()
    {
      { "00", "Menu" },
      { "14", "Menu" },
      { "18", "Topic" }
    };

  // Private constructor. Use GetContentDetails factory method.
  private ContentDetails(string refValue, string viewName)
  {
    this.RefValue = refValue;
    this.ViewName = viewName;
  }

  // Gets the RefValue.
  public string RefValue
  {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  // Gets the ViewName.
  public string ViewName
  {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  // Creates a new ContentDetails from the specified id.
  public static ContentDetails GetContentDetails(string id)
  {
    // Extract key from id.
    string key = id.Substring(2,2);

    // If key not in dictionary, use the default key "XX".
    if (!idValueDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
      key = "XX";
    }

    // Get refValue and viewName from dictionaries.
    string refValue = idValueDictionary[key];
    string viewName = valueNameDictionary[refValue];

    // Return a new ContentDetails object with properties initialized.
    return new ContentDetails(refValue, viewName);
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
// Static factory method creates a new ContentDetails from the specified `id`
ContentDetails details = ContentDetails.GetContentDetails(id);

Console.WriteLine(details.RefValue); // writes RefValue
Console.WriteLine(details.ViewName); // writes ViewName
```

Once you create a new `ContentDetails` using the `GetContentDetails` method, you then access the two properties to get the `RefValue` and `ViewName`. The properties are read-only (`private set`) so you can't change the values once a class instance is created (it's immutable). Create a new one every time you have a different `id` to look up.